# Solve 3-D Heat equation with Neumann boundaries

Tags: finite-difference, python, poisson, numerics, heat-transfer

I want to solve the Poisson PDE for heat flow in a 3-D solid cube with given dimensions $x$, $y$, and $z$:

$$\rho C\frac{\partial T}{\partial t} = k \Delta T$$

The cube is irradiated with a constant heat flux $I(x,y)$ at the $z=0$ surface. The boundaries should meet the Neumann condition for radiative cooling given by $\frac{\partial T}{\partial x_i} = \pm\epsilon\sigma(T^4-300^4)$, where the sign depends on wether you look at $x_i=$max or $x_i=0$. Due to the irradiation the $z=0$ surface is an exception, where the condition should rather be $\frac{\partial T}{\partial x_i} = \epsilon\sigma(T^4-300^4) + I(x,y)$. The last term represents the intensity distribution of the radiative flux.

I decided to go for a numerical approach I found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49463985/solving-heat-equation-with-python-numpy) thread using Python. As a result, I came up with the following piece of code.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits import mplotn3d

dt = 3
di = 0.01

#Thermal conductivity
k = 1.38
#Density
rho = 2202
#Specific Heat capacity
cp = 745
#Thermal diffusivity
alpha = k/(rho*cp)
#Emissivity
emissivity = 0.79

sigma = 5.670367e-8

y_max = 0.3
x_max = 0.3
z_max = 0.3
t_max = 60

P = 1
omega = 0.02

#Function that generates a gaussian intensity pattern I(x,y) with power P and beam waist omega

def get_beam(P, omega, di, x_max, ymax, z_max):
  x = np.arange(0,x_max+di,di)
  y = np.arange(0,y_max+di,di)
  z = np.arange(0,z_max+di,di)
  t = np.arange(0,t_max+dt,dt)
  r = len(t)
  cx = len(x)
  cy = len(y)
  cz = len(z)
  I = np.zeros([r, cx, cy, cz])
  for jx in range(0,cx-1):
      for jy in range(0,cy-1):
          I[:,jx,jy,0] = 2*P/(np.pi*omega**2)*np.exp(-2*(abs(di*(jx-cx/2))**2 + abs(di*(jy-cy/2))**2)/(omega**2))
  return I

def FTCS(dt,dy,t_max,x_max,y_max,z_max,k,T0, I):
  s = alpha*dt/di**2
  x = np.arange(0,x_max+di,di)
  y = np.arange(0,y_max+di,di)
  z = np.arange(0,z_max+di,di)
  t = np.arange(0,t_max+dt,dt)
  r = len(t)
  cx = len(x)
  cy = len(y)
  cz = len(z)
  #Initialize mesh
  T = np.ones([r,cx, cy, cz])*T0
  #time loop
  for n in range(0,r-1):  
      print(n)
      #y loop
      for jy in range(0,cy-1):   
          #x loop 
          for jx in range(0,cx-1):   
              #z loop 
              for jz in range(0,cz-1):  
                  #Compute T at next time step: Tn+1 = Tn + d^2T/dx^2 + d^2T/dy^2 + d^2T/dz^2  
                  T[n+1,jx,jy,jz] = T[n,jx,jy,jz] + s*(T[n,jx-1,jy,jz] - 2*T[n,jx,jy,jz] + T[n,jx+1,jy,jz]) + s*(T[n,jx,jy-1,jz] - 2*T[n,jx,jy,jz] + T[n,jx,jy+1,jz]) + s*(T[n,jx,jy,jz-1] - 2*T[n,jx,jy,jz] + T[n,jx,jy,jz+1]) 


      #Boundary Condition
      #Set boundary condition for x on both sides   
      T[n+1,cx-1,:,:] = T[n,cx-1,:,:] + s*(T[n,cx-2,:,:] - 2*T[n,cx-1,:,:] + T[n,cx-2,:,:] - 2*di*emissivity*sigma/k*(T[n,cx-1, :,:]**4-300**4))#- 2*di*4*emissivity*sigma/k*(T[n,cx-1,:,:]*300**3))
      T[n+1,0,:,:] = T[n,0,:,:] + s*(T[n,1,:,:] - 2*T[n,0,:,:] + T[n,1,:,:] - 2*di*emissivity*sigma/k*(T[n,0,:,:]**4-300**4))#- 2*di*4*emissivity*sigma/k*(T[n,0,:,:]*300**3))

      #Set boundary condition for y on both sides 
      T[n+1,:,cy-1,:] = T[n,:,cy-1,:] + s*(T[n,:,cy-2,:] - 2*T[n,:,cy-1,:] + T[n,:,cy-2,:] - 2*di*emissivity*sigma/k*(T[n,:,cy-1,:]**4-300**4))#- 2*di*4*emissivity*sigma/k*(T[n,:,cy-1,:]*300**3))
      T[n+1,:,0,:] = T[n,:,0,:] + s*(T[n,:,1,:] - 2*T[n,:,0,:] + T[n,:,1,:] - 2*di*emissivity*sigma/k*(T[n,:,0,:]**4-300**4))#- 2*di*4*emissivity*sigma/k*(T[n,:,0,:]*300**3))

      #Set boundary condition for z on both sides 
      T[n+1,:,:,cz-1] = T[n,:,:,cz-1] + s*(T[n,:,:,cz-2] - 2*T[n,:,:,cz-1] + T[n,:,:,cz-2] - 2*di*emissivity*sigma/k*(T[n,:,:,cz-1]**4-300**4))#- 2*di*4*emissivity*sigma/k*(T[n,:,:,cz-1]*300**3))
      T[n+1,:,:,0] = T[n,:,:,0] + s*(T[n,:,:,1] - 2*T[n,:,:,0] + T[n,:,:,1] - 2*di*emissivity*sigma/k*(T[n,:,:,0]**4-300**4) + 2*di/k*I[n,:,:,0])#- 2*di*4*emissivity*sigma/k*(T[n,:,:,0]*300**3) + 2*di*I[n,:,:,0])

  return x,y,z,t,T,r,s 

I = get_beam(P, omega, di, x_max, y_max, z_max)
x,y,z,t,T,r,s = FTCS(dt,di,t_max,x_max,y_max,z_max,k,300,I)


fig = plt.figure()
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, T[-1,:,:,0])
ax.set_xlabel('x-axis')
ax.set_ylabel('y-axis')
```

The result looks promising but is not equal to [references](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/jpa-00212444/document) I found. Furthermore, the result scales rapidly with the mesh size $d_i$ and crashes for huge point densities. I couldn't figure out whether and if so where I did a mistake. Can you help me?

//-----------------------------------//

I updated the code to include the correct boundaries. The loop looks like this now. I know its a bit clunky, but I thought I take care of it later. Nevertheless, the dependence from the mesh size is still there. I am afraid that I just forgot a $di$ somewhere, but I couldn't find out where.

```
    for n in range(0,r-1):
    print(n)
    for jy in range(0,cy-1):
        for jx in range(0,cx-1):
            for jz in range(0,cz-1):
                T[n+1,jx,jy,jz] = T[n,jx,jy,jz] + s*(T[n,jx-1,jy,jz] - 2*T[n,jx,jy,jz] + T[n,jx+1,jy,jz]) + s*(T[n,jx,jy-1,jz] - 2*T[n,jx,jy,jz] + T[n,jx,jy+1,jz]) + s*(T[n,jx,jy,jz-1] - 2*T[n,jx,jy,jz] + T[n,jx,jy,jz+1]) 

                if jx == cx-1:
                    T[n+1,jx,jy,jz] = T[n,jx,jy,jz] + s*(T[n,jx-1,jy,jz] - 2*T[n,jx,jy,jz] + T[n,jx-1,jy,jz] + 2*di*emissivity*sigma/k*(T[n,jx, jy, jz]**4-300**4)) + s*(T[n,jx,jy-1,jz] - 2*T[n,jx,jy,jz] + T[n,jx,jy+1,jz]) + s*(T[n,jx,jy,jz-1] - 2*T[n,jx,jy,jz] + T[n,jx,jy,jz+1])
                elif jx == 0:
                    T[n+1,jx,jy,jz] = T[n,jx,jy,jz] + s*(T[n,jx-1,jy,jz] - 2*T[n,jx,jy,jz] + T[n,jx-1,jy,jz] - 2*di*emissivity*sigma/k*(T[n,jx, jy, jz]**4-300**4)) + s*(T[n,jx,jy-1,jz] - 2*T[n,jx,jy,jz] + T[n,jx,jy+1,jz]) + s*(T[n,jx,jy,jz-1] - 2*T[n,jx,jy,jz] + T[n,jx,jy,jz+1]) 
                elif jy == cy-1:
                    T[n+1,jx,jy,jz] = T[n,jx,jy,jz] + s*(T[n,jx-1,jy,jz] - 2*T[n,jx,jy,jz] + T[n,jx+1,jy,jz]) + s*(T[n,jx,jy-1,jz] - 2*T[n,jx,jy,jz] + T[n,jx,jy-1,jz] + 2*di*emissivity*sigma/k*(T[n,jx,jy,jz]**4-300**4)) + s*(T[n,jx,jy,jz-1] - 2*T[n,jx,jy,jz] + T[n,jx,jy,jz+1]) 
                elif jy == 0:
                    T[n+1,jx,jy,jz] = T[n,jx,jy,jz] + s*(T[n,jx-1,jy,jz] - 2*T[n,jx,jy,jz] + T[n,jx+1,jy,jz]) + s*(T[n,jx,jy-1,jz] - 2*T[n,jx,jy,jz] + T[n,jx,jy-1,jz] - 2*di*emissivity*sigma/k*(T[n,jx,jy,jz]**4-300**4)) + s*(T[n,jx,jy,jz-1] - 2*T[n,jx,jy,jz] + T[n,jx,jy,jz+1]) 
                elif jz == cz-1:
                    T[n+1,jx,jy,jz] = T[n,jx,jy,jz] + s*(T[n,jx-1,jy,jz] - 2*T[n,jx,jy,jz] + T[n,jx+1,jy,jz]) + s*(T[n,jx,jy-1,jz] - 2*T[n,jx,jy,jz] + T[n,jx,jy+1,jz]) + s*(T[n,jx,jy,jz-1] - 2*T[n,jx,jy,jz] + T[n,jx,jy,jz-1] + 2*di*emissivity*sigma/k*(T[n,jx,jy,jz]**4-300**4)) 
                elif jz == 0:
                    T[n+1,jx,jy,jz] = T[n,jx,jy,jz] + s*(T[n,jx-1,jy,jz] - 2*T[n,jx,jy,jz] + T[n,jx+1,jy,jz]) + s*(T[n,jx,jy-1,jz] - 2*T[n,jx,jy,jz] + T[n,jx,jy+1,jz]) + s*(T[n,jx,jy,jz-1] - 2*T[n,jx,jy,jz] + T[n,jx,jy,jz-1] - 2*di*emissivity*sigma/k*(T[n,jx,jy,jz]**4-300**4) + 2*di*I[n,jx,jy,0])
```

Comment: At least one of your problems is that the forward-in-time (Euler) integration scheme is only conditionally stable. For stability, you must have $ \Delta t \le (\Delta x)^2/2 $. I suspect your large $\Delta t$ is why your solution "crashes" for fine meshes. For more information search for Courant, Friedrichs, Lewy condition.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. The crash-problems is pretty much solved when I adjust the time resolution. While writing this thread I found another mistake regarding the boundary conditions. I neglected the second derivative of the two remaining dimensions. So I included additional if statements in the inner loop:

Comment: I have updated my initial post with the new piece of code I added. Still, the other Problem occurs.

Comment: @BillGreene But the CFL condition is only for convection/advection and NOT for diffusion. For diffusion it should be $\Delta t \leq \frac{\left(\Delta x\right)^2 c_p \rho}{2 \lambda}$ (for one dimension).

Comment: @Phillip What is the ramining problem? The failing equality to the reference?

Comment: Besides that you should be able to **avoid the three innermost loops**, so that only the loop over the timestep remains. And you can catch the boundary conditions with extending your arrays by 1 into each +- direction and setting the boundary conditions there.

Comment: The solution still scales with the number of nodes I have, which can't be correct (T seems to be proportional to di). I would assume that a certain mesh density is necessary, but the result should converge to the 'real' solution for higher densities.

Comment: @Scotty1 You're right, the algorithm is clunky as hell. When I figured out the problem I might try to use matrix notation, which seems much faster to me.

Comment: Loops are bad in python, really bad. It kills the performance. Aim to vectorize your approach with numpy internals doing the loops. One error in your code seems to be, that the intensity distribution in your code should not be depending on `di`, right? So probably replacing `2*di*I[n,:,:,0]` with `I[n,:,:,0]` will help. But I am not sure about this.

Comment: @Scotty1- The di actually comes from the formulation of the boundary condition. If you have a Neumann condition d/dx T = A then you need to add A*2*di, when I am correctly.

Comment: But isn't the intensity distribution a Dirichlet condition while the radiative cooling is a Neumand condition?

Comment: Dirichlet distribution would mean a constant temperature for example. It's easier to understand if you think in terms of the physical concept. While the radiative cooling describes the heat output of the cube, the intensity is somewhat like the heat input. So same physical process, different direction. Therefor I change the sign of that boundary condition. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: Yep, my fault. Dirichlet would directly give the temperature, which is not true for the intensity. But still it should be no Neumann BC, since it is not depending on the derivative. What is the unit of the Intensity distribution? Afaik it should be (W/m^2), right?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for asking your question. It really made me delve alot deeper into the topic of boundary conditions. I am still a rookie in this topic, but I'll try to answer your question anyways.

Your major problem seems to be that your units are not correct. Your equation for radiative heat flux has the unit $[\frac{\text{W}}{\text{m}^2}]$, while the Neumann boundary condition needs a unit of $[\frac{\text{K}}{\text{m}}]$.          Your equation for the heat flux should say:

$$\frac{dq}{dt} = \epsilon \sigma \left(T^4 - 300^4 \right) + I(x,y)$$

You almost get your units correctly by multiplying this with $di/k$, resulting in $[\text{K}]$ for the radiative Stefan-Boltzmann heat transfer, but for the heat flux based on constant heat flux, you forgot the $1/k$ while still multiplying with $di$, resulting in $[\frac{\text{W}}{\text{m}}]$.

What I am not sure about is the factor of $2$. I guess this stems from a central difference scheme and thus shouldn't be correct here. But if anyone knows an explanation why this is correct/incorrect, I'd really like to know it.
Furthermore I am not sure if multiplying with $s$ is correct here. I guess you need to try all cases to and compare it with the reference solution, unless someone else with more knowledge in this topic answers.

Comment: Thank you very much for the comprehensive answer. You are absolutely right, that die Neumann condition should have units of K/m. This should be corrected by the 'k' in '2*di*emissivity*sigma/k*(T[n,:,0,:]**4-300**4)), which has the units 'W/mK' and therefor cancels out the wrong units. But I forgot the 'k' right before 'I(x,y)'.

Comment: Did it help you finding your problem?